# Was ist das korrekte Adjektiv zu Translation (math.)?

Tags: word-usage, adjective, noun

Ich muss gerade einige Affinitäten beschreiben und benötige die jeweiligen Adjektive, wie z.B.:

- Rotation: rotiert
- Skalierung: skaliert
- Scherung: geschert

Allerdings finde ich, dass "translatiert" als Adjektiv zu "Translation" etwas seltsam klingt. Ist es dennoch richtig oder gibt es ein anderes Wort dafür?

Comment: Wenn du mit einer Erklärung aus dem Lateinischen zufrieden bist: Das lat. Verb *(trans)ferre* hat die Stammformen *(trans)ferre - (trans)tuli - (trans)latum*. Das Substantiv *Translation* ist von der letzten Stammform abgeleitet, das deutsche Verb *transferieren* von der ersten. Also lautet das zugehörige deutsche Partizip Perfekt: *transferiert*.

Comment: @Chris: *Tranferieren* bedeutet im Deutschen aber weithingehend etwas anderes und wird auch in diesem Zusammenhang meines Wissens nicht verwendet. Nur das etwas etymologisch Sinn ergäbe, heißt noch lange nicht, dass es auch verwendet wird. Mal ganz abgesehen davon, dass der Zusammenhang nur mit Lateinkenntnissen ersichtlich ist. (Nichtsdestotrotz erklärt dies, warum *translatieren* nicht gebräuchlicher ist.)

Comment: @Chris Genial! Aber ich fürchte, dass man "transferieren" nicht in gesuchtem Sinne verwenden kann.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Deshalb hier nur als Kommentar und nicht als Antwort. [Ich habe mich mit einem Physik-Kommilitonen einmal genau über diesen Sachverhalt (genauer: das Verb zu *Translation*) unterhalten und wir beide benutzen seitdem das Verb *transferieren*.]

Comment: @c.p.: Ich würde das durchaus auch in bestimmten mathematischen Zusammenhängen verwenden; z. B. wenn x nach y verschoben wird, klingt es für mich nicht falsch, zu sagen: "x wird nach y transferiert" <=> "Es wird eine Translation von x nach y durchgeführt". Kann sein, dass das vergleichsweise selten so gesagt wird, aber wenn man schon ein passendes Verb zu *Translation* sucht, wäre *transferieren* meine persönliche erste Wahl (, der natürlich niemand folgen muss).

Comment: @Chris Ja, aber eben, in deinem Beispiel geht um die Translation $T_{y-x}$. Meine Ansicht: wenn man *Translation* übersetzen will, ist es wichtiger, durch welchen Punkt die Wirkung durchgeführt wird. Nennt man den Punkt $T_{w}(v)$ nicht verschoben, selbst wenn $T_w$ den Punkt $v$ nach $v+w$ tranferiert? So sagt man "um 45 Grad rotiertes Viereck". In deinem Beispiel wessentlicher ist, also, $y-x$, nicht $y$ und $x$.

Comment: @c.p.: Analog zu "um 45 Grad rotiertes Viereck" könnte man in meiner Sprechweise sagen "um w transferierter Punkt v", "um den Vektor w transferiertes Dreieck", etc. Ich weiß halt auch nicht, welche Anwendung des Partizips der Fragesteller im Sinn hatte. Wenn er mit "transferiert" nicht zufrieden ist, kann er ja immer auf "verschoben" und die anderen Vorschläge aus den Antworten zurückgreifen.

Comment: Ich kenne transliert. Das hört sich zwar seltsam an, ist aber einigermaßen verständlich.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ein etymologisch verwandtes Adjektiv gibt es im Deutschen meines Wissens [nicht](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/translatiert), dafür aber

> bewegt

als allgemeine Entsprechung und je nach Kontext etwas spezifischer:

> verschoben, versetzt.

**Edit:** [*Translatiert*](https://www.google.at/search?q=translation+biologie&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=C9vlVObYDIWxUbfggIgN#q=%22translatiert%22&tbm=bks) wird in der Biologie verwendet, jedoch nicht im Sinne von *bewegt*. Kombiniert man die Suche mit beliebigen mathematischen Stichwörtern, erzielt man auch ein paar Treffer, aber nichts substanzielles (s. Anzahl). Aus eigener Erfahrung als Mathematikstudent würde ich sagen, dass dieses Adjektiv (auch im Kontext der *Translation*) nicht verwendet wird.

Comment: Ich habe am Ende einfach das einfache Wort "verschoben" verwendet. Danke! ;-)

Comment: Übringens war mein -1 wegen *versetzt* und *bewegt*. *Rotieren* ist auch bewegen, aber mathematisch braucht man ja zwischen *rotieren* und *verschieben* zu unterscheiden.

Answer (score 4):

Wenn du den mathematischen Begriff suchst, lautet der [Verschiebung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euklidische_Transformation#Euklidische_Transformation_und_Beobachterwechsel) und das passende Adjektiv ist dann *verschoben*.  Das andere, *translatiert*, erscheint allerdings auch, nur selten, wie in Seite 18 [hier](http://www.physik.uni-kl.de/aeschlimann/lectures/EXP1SS06/11.Vorlesung01.06.06.pdf).

Also findet man in der Fachliteratur: *[verschobene (Dreh)Achse](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinerscher_Satz), verschobenes Koordinatensystem usw.* oder auch direkt aus einem konkreten Buch Linearer Algebra, [verschobener Punkt](https://books.google.de/books?id=DmgGBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA463&lpg=PA463&dq=%22verschobenen+Punkt%22&source=bl&ots=0o1d06pm8s&sig=l6Kg5XGeCYChLj-qullts18HNl0&hl=de&sa=X&ei=rNrlVJ_NIYKzUdfLgZgG&ved=0CDoQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=%22verschobenen%20Punkt%22&f=false).

In der Biologie existiert ebenfalls der Fachterminus [*Translation*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28Biologie%29), wessen  Adjektivisierung *translatiert* bleiben muss.

Comment: Man kann es sowohl konstruieren als auch verstehen, *in Gebrauch* ist es aber nicht – nicht einmal der verlinkte Wikipedia-Artikel dazu verwendet es.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: [Es wird durchaus in der Fachliteratur verwendet.](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22translatieren%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_de)

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Interessant. Ich suchte allerdings auch nach dem Adjektiv.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: [Ändert nicht viel](https://www.google.de/search?q=%22translatiert%22&tbs=bks%3A1&lr=lang_de). Und selbst wenn, kann man immer das *translatiert* als Partizip zu *translatieren* bilden.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Jetzt fehlt nur noch die *richtige* Fachliteratur.

Comment: @Grantwalzer Die *richtige* Fachliteratur wird seit langem auf Englisch geschrieben. Leider :) aber ich versuche, was zu finden.

Comment: @c.p. Haha, ja^^

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Wenn ich mich nicht täusche, sind das meiste unter den Links akademische Lehrbücher. Wesentlich fachlicher geht es kaum.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Zweifellos – ich würde mir niemals anmaßen, die fachliche Richtigkeit von Büchern, die ich nicht gelesen habe, und die ich, würde ich sie auch lesen, wahrscheinlich nicht verstünde, beurteilen zu können.

Answer (score 1):

In der Mathematik ist das Wort, das Du suchst, *Verschiebung*.

Comment: Das Wort was ich suche ist ein Adjektiv, *Verschiebung* ist ein Substantiv. ;)

Comment: *Verschoben* dann.

Comment: @MartinPeters: Du kannst (und solltest) Korrekturen an Deinen Antworten selbst vornehmen, nicht nur in Kommentaren. Allerdings mangelt es dieser Antwort auch dann an Mehrwert gegenüber den existierenden Antworten.